# Indexing staking/rewards events for NEAR blockchain

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to create an app to have a detailed info about historical stake and reward changes for each block. Can I track every delegation events that contain any stake balance changes of delegator/validator? Including information like:

- delegator address
- validator address
- amount of tokens that got delegated, undelegated or receive rewards

I found [this contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/staking-pool#interface). And then I tried decode transaction's actions and receipts. I still can not find info about amount.

For example [this transaction](https://explorer.mainnet.near.org/transactions/BRdXMCc5Ug7XbvoUqy51Ctjsa716ywLB7tApvCa2YjcB) contain `unstake_all` method. I tried using Near REST API or Postgres DB like

```
postgres://public_readonly:nearprotocol@mainnet.db.explorer.indexer.near.dev/mainnet_explorer
```

But, it does not include info about amount but explorer does:

```
@ojosdepez.near unstaking 211362599667478202066742666. Spent 186315320307823908119982990 staking shares. Total 211362599667478202066742667 unstaked balance and 0 staking shares
Contract total staked balance is 18374491513732210121091349309226. Total number of shares 16197043740284605773282183202762
```

So can I somehow get these logs using REST API or Postgres and are these logs reliable source? Or if there is any other method to find staking/reward amount info?

Answer (score 1):

First of all

> But, it does not include info about the amount but explorer does:

```
@ojosdepez.near unstaking 211362599667478202066742666. Spent 186315320307823908119982990 staking shares. Total 211362599667478202066742667 unstaked balance and 0 staking shares
Contract total staked balance is 18374491513732210121091349309226. Total number of shares 16197043740284605773282183202762
```

Explorer queries the RPC and shows you the logs from `ExecutionOutcome`.

In the PostgreSQL database for Indexer for Explorer, we don't store logs, so you can't find them there.

---

To have a detailed info about historical stake and reward changes for each block, I think you should index the blockchain by yourself to be sure everything is calculated as you expected.

In order to do this, you'd need to build an indexer. Happily, we're releasing an MVP (yet completely working solution) of [`NEAR Lake Framework`](https://github.com/near/near-lake-framework) which is a microframework to build indexers but even easier than it is done before now.

Please, have a look at the example project https://github.com/near/near-lake-raw-printer which basically prints the data from each block. Refer to this comment as an example of the structure that you can receive for each block (`StreamerMessage`) https://github.com/near/near-lake/issues/1#issuecomment-1035285658

So the **main idea** is to start indexing from the block where rewards became available (Phase 2) and analyze each block, transaction, and receipt related to staking/unstaking so you can perform your calculations and record the info about historical stake and reward changes.